# JQuery Replace String In Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the string within an `attr('src')` in just the beginning of the address, and after the replacement, it keeps the latter information.
Here's the html:

```
<img src="../folder1/folder2/folder3/picture.png" />

<img src="../folder1/folder2/folder3/picture2.png" />
```

It would need to perform this after pageload, here's my existing script/scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    // this is one attempt
    $('img').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).ready(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src.replace('../', '/'));
        }, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        });
    });

    // this is another attempt, not both used at the same time
    $('img').attr('src').replace('../', '/');

    // I also tried this
    $('img').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('src') == '../') {
            $(this).attr('src', '/');
        };
    });
});
```

The overall goal is to produce this result:

```
<img src="/folder1/folder2/folder3/picture.png" />

<img src="/folder1/folder2/folder3/picture2.png" />
```

Comment: this.src, don't need the extra jquery objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the current `src` - update it, then re-assign it:

```
$('img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
    return src.replace('../', '/')
})
```

Comment: my data server went down, your solution works in a small jsfiddle, I'll flag as answer as soon as I can test on the server :)